# If a vector field is divergenceless and curless, is that vector field = 0?

Tags: vector-analysis

Just a simple question, from the title of the thread, is a vector field = 0 if the divergence is 0 and the curl is 0? I had trouble finding an answer anywhere online, proof of why or why not would be helpful, thanks!

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = 0$$
$$\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0$$
$$\vec{F} = ?$$

Comment: sorry i dont know how to write the $del $symbol.
if $\Delta .F=0$ and $\Delta*F=0$ implies 
$$F_x+F_y+F_z=0$$
it does not imply $F=0$

Comment: @ Surah M.S.:  latex for $\Delta$, is "\Delta"; for $\nabla$, it's "\nabla", the centralized dot, $\cdot$, is "\cdot".  So $\nabla \cdot F$ is "\nabla \cdot F".  You might find it helpful to check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  To get a feel for what's up, let $\phi$ be a non-constant harmonic function so $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ but $\nabla \phi \ne 0$.  Set $\mathbf F = \nabla \phi \ne 0$; then   Then $\nabla \times \mathbf F = \nabla \times \nabla \phi = 0, \,$ since the curl of a gradient always vanishes.  Also, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf F = \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi = \nabla^2 \phi = 0$.  The divergence and curl of $\mathbf F$ both vanish, but not $\mathbf F$!

This line of reasoning can, like tape or film, be re-wound and run "backwards":  if $\mathbf F \ne 0$ and $\nabla \times \mathbf F = 0$, then (locally at least) there is a function $\phi$ with $\mathbf F = \nabla \phi \ne 0$; if now we also have $\nabla \cdot \mathbf F = 0$, then $\nabla^2 \phi = \nabla \cdot \nabla \phi = \nabla \cdot \mathbf F = 0$, and $\phi$ is harmonic.

The classic examples of such a field may be found in the elementary theory of electromagnetism:  in the absence of sources, that is, charges and currents, static (non -time varying) electric fields $\mathbf E$ and magnetic fields $\mathbf B$ have vanishing divergence and curl:  $\nabla \times \mathbf B = \nabla \times \mathbf E = 0$, and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf B = \nabla \cdot \mathbf E = 0$; the electrostatic potential function $\phi$ such that $\mathbf E = -\nabla \phi$ with $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ exists by virtue of these facts; a similar assertion holds for the $\mathbf B$ field.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always (as ol' James Clerk M. has taught us),

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Yes, "Fiat lux" is appropriate here. Could you explain why it keeps appearing elsewhere?

Comment: @ dfeuer:  tell you what:  check out the late W. Thurston's ansswer to this question:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43690/whats-a-mathematician-to-do and get back to me!  Regards, RKL

Comment: thanks! great answer, I even noticed I came across one of these types of fields shortly after in some E&M problems I was working on with constant potential boundaries =)

Comment: @Spaderdabomb:  and I thank you!  Glad to help out.  And yeah, these fields are all over the place!  P.S.  muchas gracias for the "acceptance" as well.

Answer (score 6):

No. Just consider a nonzero constant vector field, i.e. 
$$V=(a,b,c)$$
for some nonzero constants $a, b, c$. 
Then the curl of $V$ is zero vector, and the divergence of $V$ is $0$.

Comment: Constants are always so damn *useful* as a source of examples, aren't they?  Though belated, ***plus one!!!***

Answer (score 1):

For example $\vec{u} = (x+y, x-y, 0)$ has $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{u}=0$ and $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{u}=0$.
See picture here: [image: http://newtechno.altervista.org/documenti/Corso_di_fisica/campo1.gif]

Answer (score -1):

No. For example, if we consider simple 2 dimension field,

$\vec{V} = a (x,-y) $     ,  for any scalar $a$ then

$ \vec{\nabla} . \vec{V} = 0 $ and 
$ \vec{\nabla} \times  \vec{V} = 0 $